# Homework: How to sort an Array List of String coming from a file

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, stringtokenizer

I need to Write a program that reads in the following information from a file. The columns are: Time in 1/100 second ticks, Note Number, Velocity, Length. And each line is a different note I need to Write a program that reads them in, and then prints them out again. I want to have one public class for Note, and an array of them.

```
0 60 100 24
25 72 100 24
100 60 100 24
50 60 100 24
75 72 100 24
```

This is my new Note class

public class Note implements Comparable {

```
private int time;
private int noteNumber;
private int velocity;
private int length;

public Note (int time, int noteNumber, int velocity, int length){

    this.time = time;
    this.noteNumber = noteNumber;
    this.velocity = velocity;
    this.length = length;

}


public String toString (){

    return String.format("(%s, %d, %d, %d)", time, noteNumber, velocity, length);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Note note) {

    return this.time - note.time;
}
```

}

This is the class that I am using to read lines from the file. I am able to store correctly only the first line, but now I am having issues trying to store the other lines.

public class MelodyCatcher{

public static Note[] n = new Note[5];

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

FileReader fr = new FileReader ("/Users/enricomomo/Desktop/Text/file1.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr); //Info stored into a buffer

    String ln = null;
    while ((ln = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(ln);
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) // read each number in this line
    {

        n[0] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
        n[1] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
        n[2] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
        n[3] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
        n[4] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));

    }

    System.out.println("The notes are " + Arrays.toString(n));
    Arrays.sort(n);
    System.out.println("The notes stored are " + Arrays.toString(n));
}

br.close();
fr.close();
```

}
}

Comment: Please substantially improve the Markdown formatting of this comment and reduce the code (for instance by deleting whitespace) so it;s not so long.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am stuck, I have no idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry I did not know that, I will do it now

Comment: Also, if you have a question, you should say so in your question.

Comment: It is bad style to initialize your fields. Initialize them in a constructor.

Comment: Also public Note melody[] = new Note[5] is incorrect and I'm surprised you didn't get a compiler error. It should be Note[] melody = new Note[5]

Comment: I modified the code to show you what I have achieved so far

Answer (score 1):

So, if your lines look like as in example, you can simple split line to Note object as below:

```
String[] noteParams = ln.split(" ");
Note n = new Note(noteParams[0], noteParams[1], noteParams[2], noteParams[3]);
```

I can change your code as below to read every line and fill Note array:

```
    String ln = null;
    while ((ln = br.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(ln);
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) // read each number in this line
        {

            n[0] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            n[1] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            n[2] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            n[3] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            n[4] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));

        }

        System.out.println("The notes are " + Arrays.toString(n));
        Arrays.sort(n);
        System.out.println("The notes stored are " + Arrays.toString(n));
    }

    br.close();
    fr.close();
```

Comment: Do u need something more? If this solved your problem could u please mark it as approved? It is on the left side of answer.

Comment: I am still trying to work it out. I made everything simpler. Now I can read a line from file and store it, but I can not read the remaining lines

Comment: If you are using Java version 8, u can read file as a stream and then process lines very simple way. Please take a look example at https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/

Comment: I modified the code, so now you can better see what I am trying to achieve. I can correctly read and store the first line now, but not the other line

Comment: If you run it like that it works, and it correctly stores the first line:                                                                                                                                                                   
       while(st.hasMoreTokens()) // read each number in this line
        {

           n[0] = new Note(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));

        }

Comment: Ok, please check my answer I added required changes to support your code

Comment: I made the change as you can see above; but still It gives me error and I am not able to print the content of the array

Comment: Probably u have a wrong at String format. instead of `return String.format("(%s, %d, %d, %d)` please use below:

`return String.format("(%s, %s, %s, %s)`